# Initializing an input in a form for submission

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to send an API post through my flutter app:

The user inserts the log_weight through a textfield which inside table inside a Form. The row of the table are iterations from a list.

In my flutter app I have created a table that iterates through a list inside a form. So I am trying to get a log submission from each iteration.

Here is my api_serice.dart:

```
class APIService {
  static var client = http.Client();
  Future<http.Response> addLog(
      int logWeight) async {
    var url = Uri.parse(Config.apiURL +
        Config.userAddlogAPI);

    final response = await http.post(url, headers: {
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
          'Token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    }, body: {
      'log_weight': logWeight,
    });
  }
```

Here is the exercises.dart:

```
class Exercises extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExercisesState createState() => _ExercisesState();
}

class _ExercisesState extends State<Exercises> {
  late Map<String, int> arguments;
  late int logWeight;
```

Here is the form:

```
 Builder(builder: (context) {
                                          return Form(
                                            key: key,
                                            child: Table(
                                              children: [
                                                const TableRow(children: [
                                                  Text(
                                                    '',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 15,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold,
                                                      color: Colors.black,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  Text(
                                                    'Weight',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 15,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold,
                                                      color: Colors.black,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  Text(
                                                    'New Weight',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 15,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold,
                                                      color: Colors.black,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  Text(
                                                    'Submit',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 15,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold,
                                                      color: Colors.black,
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                ]),

                                                // Iterate over the breakdowns list and display the sequence information
                                                for (var breakdown in snapshot
                                                    .data![index].breakdowns)
                                                  TableRow(children: [
                                                    Text(
                                                      '${breakdown.order}',
                                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 15,
                                                        color: Colors.black,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                    Text(
                                                      '${breakdown.weight}',
                                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 15,
                                                        color: Colors.black,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                    TextFormField(
                                                      decoration:
                                                          InputDecoration(
                                                        border:
                                                            InputBorder.none,
                                                      ),
                                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 15,
                                                        color: Colors.black,
                                                      ),
                                                      validator: (value) {
                                                        if (value == null) {
                                                          return 'Please enter a valid number';
                                                        }
                                                        return null;
                                                      },
                                                      onSaved: (value) {
                                                        logWeight =
                                                            int.parse(value!);
                                                      },
                                                    ),
                                                    OutlinedButton(
                                                      onPressed: () async {
                                                        final Map<String, int>
                                                            arguments =
                                                            ModalRoute.of(
                                                                        context)!
                                                                    .settings
                                                                    .arguments
                                                                as Map<String,
                                                                    int>;
                                                        final int id =
                                                            arguments['id'] ??
                                                                0;
                                                        try {
                                                          if (Form.of(context)
                                                                  ?.validate() ==
                                                              true) {
                                                            Form.of(context)
                                                                ?.save();

                                                            APIService.addLog(
                                                                id,
                                                                logWeight);
                                                          }
                                                        } catch (error) {
                                                          await showDialog(
                                                            context: context,
                                                            builder: (context) {
                                                              return AlertDialog(
                                                                title: Text(
                                                                    'Error'),
                                                                content: Text(error
                                                                    .toString()),
                                                                actions: [
                                                                  OutlinedButton(
                                                                    child: Text(
                                                                        'OK'),
                                                                    onPressed:
                                                                        () {
                                                                      Navigator.of(
                                                                              context)
                                                                          .pop();
                                                                    }, ),],);},);}},
                                                      child: Text('Submit'),
                                                    ),]),],),);
```

How can I fix my code so that I can send the log_weight. I keep getting `E/flutter ( 4353): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field 'logWeight' has not been initialized.`

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by `late` keyword. variables that are late must be initialized. Try not to use late that much.

Solution 1. make logWeight non-nullable and initialize it. Because your `addLog` method only allows non-nullable logWeight value.

```
 int logWeight = 0;
```

Solution 2. make logWeight nullable and before calling the api, check if it's null or not. (If logWeight is required param for your api)

```
int? logWeight;
---

if(logWeight != null) {
   APIService.addLog(id,logWeight);
}

or use validation
```

Solution 3. (If logWeight is not required param for your api) just make logWeight nullable and change your method to allow nullable logWeight value

```
int? logWeight;
---

class APIService {
  static var client = http.Client();
  Future<http.Response> addLog(
      int? logWeight) async {
...
}
```